# Wordpress scroll to comment

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

In wordpress when a comment is posted the page refreshes and scrolls to the comment, but what I need to do is that the jquery automatically animate the scroll to that comment. The problem is that when I take the hash from url and find the comment with that Id it shows it's location is 0 but it's not.

```
var hash, hash_s;
if( window.location.hash ) {
    hash = $( '#' + window.location.hash.substring( 1 ) );

    if( hash ) {
        hash_s = hash.position( ).top;
        console.log( hash_s );

        body.animate( { scrollTop: hash_s }, 600 );
    }
}

console.log( hash_s ) outputs value 0
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  [offset](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) `hash.offset( ).top;`  to get the value relative to the document

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about this :D